# Squarespace developer mode href buttons or links not clicking through disabled.. FIXED

Tags: css, href, squarespace

I am making Squarespace developer mode edits to a template ".region" file, I have added stock standard HREF tag links like these (they should be working):

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

but they seem to be disabled. they do not click through. I can't find any documentation online or on Squarespace dev docs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have found a work around for this, i hope this will help someone out there.. i wasted nearly a day looking into this (even contacting their support, which they didnt have an answer).

HTML code

```
<a class="LINK" href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

CSS code

```
.LINK{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px; /* i was using this as i was adding icons - but maybe set this to auto*/
    height: 20px;/* i was using this as i was adding icons - but maybe set this to auto*/
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

Comment: @ceejayoz well it did wok for me perfectly and fixed my issue.. so yes it works. why do you say "unlikely" when you don't know for certain?